# Does anyone know if this is polynomially solvable?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, np-hard

Hi, I'm dealing with the following problem.

You are given a matrix of size M x N with positive coefficients. The goal is to choose P columns such that maximal sum of all elements in each row of the resulting M x P matrix is minimized. For example, if M = 3, N = 5, P = 2 and matrix is given by

a<sub>11</sub> a<sub>12</sub> a<sub>13</sub> a<sub>14</sub> a<sub>15</sub> 
a<sub>21</sub> a<sub>22</sub> a<sub>23</sub> a<sub>24</sub> a<sub>25</sub> 
a<sub>31</sub> a<sub>32</sub> a<sub>33</sub>`a<sub>34</sub> a<sub>35</sub>

and the optimal solution is to choose `columns 2 and 4, the resulting matrix is given by

a<sub>12</sub> a<sub>14</sub> 
a<sub>22</sub> a<sub>24</sub> 
a<sub>32</sub> a<sub>34</sub>

and the value max{a<sub>12</sub> + a<sub>14</sub>, a<sub>22</sub> + a<sub>24</sub>, a<sub>32</sub> + a<sub>34</sub>} is minimal among all choices of P columns.

Since there are (N over P) solutions, one can implement an easy exponential algorithm to solve this problem, but is there any faster, polynomial-time solution to this?

Or, if there is not, can anyone surely prove this is an NP-hard problem? Do you know any similar NP-hard problem that might be reduced to this one?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is NP-hard because if you could solve your problem, then you could solve [minimum vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

### Sketch of proof

The approach would be to define a matrix with a column for each vertex and a row for each edge.

In row j, corresponding to an edge between vertices x and y, put every element to 0, except at columns x and y place a 1.

If we can choose P columns such that the max of the row sums are <= 1, then we know that the remaining columns correspond to a vertex cover of the original graph.

(The rows sum being <= 1 means that the P columns selected can only contain at most 1 of x and y, and so at least 1 of x and y must be included in our vertex cover.)

By using bisection we could work out the largest P for which this is true, and hence deduce the size of the minimum vertex cover.

Comment: I think a comparison with the complimentary, equivalently difficult maximal independent set problem might be a little clearer.  The problem is equivalent, just more directly related to P